# Archiving DB tables in SQL Server: same DB or a different database?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, database-design

Our DBA team is working on an archival process for some of the larger databases. And there’s a difference of opinion on whether to keep the data in the same database or in a different database.

I have done some research and come-up with the following points. Is there a best practice? Is one way better than other.

Option A: Same DB

- Easier to implement  (+)
- Can have a view to  join active and archived data (+)
- Single database (+)
- Easier to move to a different server, if you have to (++)

Option B: Different DB

- Smaller operational database (+++)
- Smaller maintenance window for operational DB (++)
- Short time to restore operational DB on a non-prod environment  (++)
- DB count (twice) (-)
- View needs to cross database boundaries (-)

Comment: Thank you marc_s for editing! appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely Option B (i.e. Separate database). In fact, depending on the size of all of the archived data, you might even consider moving it to a completely different instance of SQL Server.

As for the pros and cons, I disagree with some of them for Option B:

- The View needing to cross databases is, realistically, not an issue at all.
- Having 2 databases instead of 1 is not an issue.
- With a separate DB, the archived data can be managed / indexed, etc differently, so (+).

In the end, if the data has been deemed "non-transactional" such that it can be archived, then it shouldn't be in the transactional DB. You touched on this in the point about "Smaller maintenance window for operational DB". The goal is to improve performance and managability of the transactional system.